# mysql join Two tables to get records

Tags: mysql, join, foreign-keys

Hai guys,

I have two tables **Incharge** and **property**. My property table has three fields 1stIncharge,2ndIncharge and 3rdIncharge. InchargeId is set as foreign key for all the above fields in the property table..

How to write a select statement that joins both the table.. I ve tried a bit but no result

```
select P.Id,P.Name,P.1stIncharge,P.2ndIncharge,P.3rdIncharge,I.Id from 
Property as P join Incharge as I where (\\How to give condition here \\)
```

**Guys 3 fields P.1stIncharge, P.2ndIncharge, P.3rdIncharge has foreign key I.Id**

**Edit:**

```
select P.Id,P.Name,P.1stIncharge,P.2ndIncharge,P.3rdIncharge,I1.Id from 
Property as P 
inner join Incharge as I1 on I1.Id=P.1stIncharge 
inner join Incharge as I2 on I2.Id=P.2ndIncharge  
inner join Incharge as I3 on I3.Id=P.3rdIncharge

and this query working
```

Comment: @Saranya: If Codesleuth's solution is not what you wanted, consider editing your question and providing example data about expected results.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your foreign key names from both tables, but I think you're looking for this:

```
SELECT P.Id, P.Name, P.1stIncharge, P.2ndIncharge, P.3rdIncharge, I.Id
FROM Property as P INNER JOIN Incharge as I ON P.InchargeId = I.Id
```

Comment: @Codesleuth 3 fields P.1stIncharge, P.2ndIncharge, P.3rdIncharge has foreign key I.Id

Comment: @Codesleuth there is no field called P.InchargeId

Comment: Sorry, but your question was a bit vague. I'm glad you sorted it though.

Answer (score 0):

If your table and column names are correct, your provided solution looks ok (I reformatted it):

```
SELECT
  P.Id, P.Name, P.1stIncharge, P.2ndIncharge, P.3rdIncharge,
  I1.Id
FROM Property AS P
JOIN Incharge AS I1 ON ( I1.Id = P.1stIncharge )
JOIN Incharge AS I2 ON ( I2.Id = P.2ndIncharge )
JOIN Incharge AS I3 ON ( I3.Id = P.3rdIncharge )
```

What kind of error do you get?